# Python regular expression, using dots many times

Tags: python, regex

In python regular expressions, if I want to write 20 dots in a row because I want 20 characters, how can I do this in shorthand?

Comment: What does that mean: *I want to write 20 dots in a row because I want 20 characters*? Provide examples, expected behavior, your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

use `'.{20}'`

```
In [15]: x = 'a'  * 30 + '.' * 20 + 'b' * 30
In [16]: m = re.search('.{20}', x)
In [17]: m
Out[17]: <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x103ec3850>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print '.'*20
```

Searching in internet should solve your problem before posting that...

Comment: I think Edward meant matching 20 characters